# Content not loading in Lazy Load module routines in Angular 2

Tags: angular2-routing

I have separated routing for modules.

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import appRoutes from "./app.routing";

import { HomeComponent  } from "./app.routing";

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, appRoutes ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

This is my app.routing.ts

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    template : `I am from home`
})

export class HomeComponent {}


const routes = [
    {
        path : "",
        component : HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path : "contact",
        loadChildren : "app/contact/contact.module"
    }

];

export default RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

This is my contact.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";

import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";

import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { ContactComponent } from "./contact.component";


const routes = [
    {path : "contact", component : ContactComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ CommonModule, RouterModule.forChild(routes) ],
  declarations: [ ContactComponent ],
})

export default class ContactModule {

}
```

HomeComponent link is working fine. But If I contact route no contents are displayed in browsers

I cannot find what the issue is. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must specify the name of the module you're trying to load:

```
loadChildren : "app/contact/contact.module#ContactModule"
```